# Can I convert spaces to tabs?

Tags: intellij-idea

Can I convert spaces to tabs in IntelliJ? I'm editing my source code in Sublime Text while my workmates uses IntelliJ. IntelliJ always change my tabs into spaces. I've changed my settings here:

[image]

But it only affects new files. How can I include the old files in the process?

Comment: what OS are you on? if you're on a *nix system you could use `tr`

Comment: I think OP wants to do this in IntelliJ as his colleagues are getting pissed at him

Comment: @the_ My computer and my colleagues both has Windows OS.

Comment: reformat code will ensure all files reformatted have the correct tabs/spaces settings BUT it will also do all the other formatting, so may be ok, but you'd have to decide.

Otherwise, it looks like its file-by-file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for the current file:

[image]

Comment: How to do this for entire project with hundreds of files?

Comment: @Carmageddon perl. I don't think IntelliJ can do that right now, but perl definitely can.

Comment: There is actually a way to do this, I got the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156873/how-to-force-intellij-idea-to-convert-all-java-files-from-spaces-to-tabs